Protect API requiring Bearer token (Python - Flask - OIDC)
I'm trying to protect my Web Application API requiring an authentication (Bearer token). I am using an IdentityProvider (Authentik - OAuth2) for the authentication.
What I am using

python 3.12
Authentik (the Identity Provider aka IdP)
Flask (to expose the API)
authlib (to handle OAuth2 Session)

What I've done
I created the webapp
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
oauth = OAuth(app)
authentik = oauth.register(
    name='authentik',
    client_id=app.config['AUTHENTIK_CLIENT_ID'],
    client_secret=app.config['AUTHENTIK_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    server_metadata_url=app.config['AUTHENTIK_DISCOVERY_URL'],
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'openid profile email',
    }
)

I defined a function to validate Bearer Token
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        auth_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if auth_header:
            try:
                token = auth_header.split(" ")[1]
                # Here you should verify the token with your IdP (authentik)
                nonce = session.get('user').get('nonce')
                print(nonce)
                print(token)
                user_info = oauth.authentik.parse_id_token(token, nonce)
                if not user_info:
                    return jsonify({"message": "Token is invalid"}), 401
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Errore ..."+str(e))
                return jsonify({"message": "Token is invalid"}), 401
        else:
            return jsonify({"message": "Token is missing"}), 401
    return decorated_function

and of course I defined some endpoint:
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorize', _external=True)
    return authentik.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri)

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    token = oauth.authentik.authorize_access_token()
    user_info = token.get('userinfo')
    # Save user_info in the session or handle it as needed
    session['user'] = user_info
    return jsonify(token)


@app.route('/api/protected')
@token_required
def protected():
    return jsonify({"message": "This is a protected endpoint!"})

The login works well and I'm able to get userinfo, the access_token and the id_token.

But if I try to send a request to protected api (http://localhost:5000/api/protected) using either the access_token or the id_token, I cannot authenticate.
When I send the GET request with an Authorization header like Bearer eyJhbGc[...]asdasdad I get an error of invalid token.
I cannot understand where is the error and where I can find a valid Bearer token.
